# Linksys L2TP VPN Disconnecting

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I am using a 2nd router as a L2TP VPN Router. Whenever the router boots up, it connects to VPN for about 2 minutes, then it disconnects. It stays in a "connecting" state and never regains a connection.

Does anyone know why this would happen? Does anyone know what other settings I could use to fix this issue?

I want a persistent L2TP VPN connection when connected to the 2nd router.

Details:

- Internet router is at 10.0.0.1
- 2nd Router is at 10.0.1.1
- 2nd Router has keep alive set to 30 seconds.
- 2nd Router has MTU set to AUTO.
- Internet router LAN port 1 is connected to 2nd Router's WAN port.
- 2nd Router is a Linksys EA4500 with latest linksys firmware.
- Everything connected to the internet router has a working internet connection without issues.